# wkhtmltopdf is not rendering fonts and border-radius is incorrect

Tags: qt, fonts, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a couple of problems with wkhtmltopdf. 
I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2 (with patched qt)

I am converting a custom html page to a PDF. The rendered html looks correct on the browser, fonts rendered correctly, border-radius working fine. All that I expected.

When I run the wkhtmltopdf program with the rendered html page as input, some of the styling is rendered but the fonts are not.

I am using a custom font called Brandon Grotesque. 
I have tried importing it a myriad of ways

1. Serving it locally on my site
2. Using base64 encoding
3. Installing the font locally on the machine
4. I also tried importing the file from AWS S3 at one point :)

Here are the screenshots of the problem
This is the screenshot of the rendered HTML page that will serve as input
[image]

This is the screenshot of the PDF output
[image]

Lastly, this is the command that I am using to get the results

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf --encoding 'utf-8' --print-media-type --page-width 5in --page-height 7in -B 20 -L 5 -R 5 -T 5 --footer-html http://localhost:6116/packing_slip/footer http://localhost:6116/packing_slip/render?<some_query_string> /tmp/packing_slips/32345447_BEWZy_.pdf
```

Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

It turns out the font is actually what I was expecting. However, wkhtmltopdf made it bold and removed letter spacing, making it unrecognizable.

For the image. I just had to adjust CSS to make the pdf render a full circle, even though the browser already rendered it properly.

Comment: Hello, could you please post you css code? I got border and border-radius conflicting so I had to remove border-radius. Maybe there is a workaround for it?

Comment: Yes, please post the CSS. Thanks.